# install disks with raid on a controller of the same model? without losing data. hp dl160 g9 - b140i

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have an HP DL160 Gen 9 server with 4 disk drives, 2 HDD with RAID 1 and 2 SSD with RAID 1.
This server is restarting repeatedly when the esxi System boots.
If I install these 4 disks on an identical server with the same controller model and same server model, will I be able to restore this raid without losing the data?

Comment: Some RAID controllers have the option to import disks from the same controller type/vendor/... However, you should *always* have a current, verified backup, there's no guarantee an import will work.

Comment: `Will I be able to restore this raid without losing the data?` Yes. Otherwise, if you had to replace the Raid controller you would need to restore the storage configuration.

Comment: The configuration is stored both on the controller and in the disk's metadata.  If the controller has no configuration, it asks the disks. The disks should go into the same slots in the new server as they were in the old one. If the controller has a config and it differs from the config on the disks, it will ask you "Config mismatch - save?".  It does not tell you which config it will save to where, so it's safer to delete the config from the controller (without the disks inserted) first, then insert the disks (server powered off). But valid as always: have a working backup.